# TOC Section & Subsection coloring

Tags: table-of-contents, color

Is it possible to create a TOC with section headings in one color and subsection headings in different color.

```
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
```

I am using above lines to create TOC, do I need to use any special package?

Comment: Please don't post an answer in the question. This only confuses people who read the question later on. You should add an answer with this solution (and clearly state that it is just a variation of Stefan's answer).

Comment: I did not how to post answer back, so I edited the post. I did not know I can answer my own question. I have restored the original post

Comment: If you want to, you can still take what you just deleted and post it as an _answer_.

Comment: there is an answer form at the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package for customizing the table of contents.

Without an additional package, you could modify the class macros which are responsible for the table of contents entries, such as `\l@section` and `\l@subsection`.

Here is an example for the `article` class:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\let\stdl@section\l@section
\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
  \stdl@section{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}}
\let\stdl@subsection\l@subsection
\renewcommand*{\l@subsection}[2]{%
  \stdl@subsection{\textcolor{DarkGreen}{#1}}{\textcolor{DarkGreen}{#2}}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\section{Section Two}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\subsection{Subsection Two}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have forgotten the subsubsection: \renewcommand*{\l@subsubsection}[2]{% \stdl@subsection{\hspace{1cm}\textcolor{TheColorIWant}{#1}}{\textcolor{TheColorIWant}{#2}}} Here we need the \hspace command because \stdl@subsubsection doesn't exist

Comment: @Álvaro: I did not forget the subsubsection, as it was asked just for section and subsection, but thanks for the addition. Btw. I converted your answer to a comment, as it's more a comment to the other answer.

Comment: I got the desired colors from the answer above, but the toc is no longer hyperlinked. If I use the hyperref package, it screws with the colors, only page numbers are colored, though the toc is clickable. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've just solve it!

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\color{ColorTerciario}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecaftersnumb}{\hspace{0.5em}}

\makeatletter %colorear la tabla de contenidos, extraído de http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7526/toc-section-subsection-coloring/56368#56368
    \let\stdl@section\l@section
    \renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
        \stdl@section{\textcolor{ColorPrincipal}{#1}}{\textcolor{ColorPrincipal}{#2}}}
    \let\stdl@subsection\l@subsection
    \renewcommand*{\l@subsection}[2]{%
        \stdl@subsection{\textcolor{ColorSecundario}{#1}}{\textcolor{ColorSecundario}{#2}}}
```

The space can be varied with the `cftsubsubsecaftersnumb`.