# Remove dots & Page numbers from TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using example given here by @stephan [TOC Section & Subsection coloring](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7526/toc-section-subsection-coloring). 
Works great however I want to get rid of dots and page numbers.

I added this to the preamble

```
\let\Contentsline\contentsline 
\renewcommand\contentsline[3]{\Contentsline{#1}{#2}{}}
```

that removed the page numbers, but do not know how to remove the dots. I would appreciate your help. Its hard to get result without understanding the basics.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Method - 1: Add

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000} 
\makeatother
```

in your preamble.

Method - 2:
This can be achieved by `tocloft` package also. Here one has to use

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
```

to remove the page numbers and

```
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
```

to remove the dots.

A MWE will be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
% \cftpagenumbersoff{chapters}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{section}} %% Similarly for subsection, figure... as you wish
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{} %empty {} for no dots. you can have any symbol inside. For example put {\ensuremath{\ast}} and see what happens.
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{one}

\section{one}

\end{document}
```

Comment: method-1 worked great, thanks for your help.

Comment: method 2- does not work on \listofalgorithms, but method 1 works... thanks!