# Completely remove page numbers, including inside TOC references, using bullet sections

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdftex, page-numbering, ebook

I'm taking study notes in latex and I want to read it in my kindle.
So far I was able to get very good results using:

```
\documentclass[ebook,oneside,openany,17pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

But for an e-reader is really helpful the TOC with links, and as I found useless the page numbering in an e-reader, I just want to remove it (also it looks very bad with `0.3in` margin) from the the pages in the final pdf and **from the TOC at the right end**.

In order to remove the page numbers I've used:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

But now I have several issues:

1. With the command `\thispagestyle{empty}` the TOC is empty.
2. If I remove `\thispagestyle{empty}`, still the TOC is empty (I think is because I use the * form for chapters, sections, etc.)
3. When I remove `\thispagestyle{empty}` and use the numbered sectioning then the TOC have page numbers at the right side.

What I want is:

- No page numbering at all, not in pages nor in TOC.
- If it is possible no numbered sectioning.
- Hyperlinks (this part is working just fine right now).

I hope here I could find a complete solution.

---

Note: I've tried with this [Remove dots & Page numbers from TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55465/remove-dots-page-numbers-from-toc) with no luck, I think one big problem in my approach could be the use of `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ebook,oneside,openany,17pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=0.3in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage[backref,hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Notes about something}
\author{Me}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter*{First thought}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section*{Complications}

\subsection*{OK}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I will do it i a minute, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Just added the MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should serve as a starting point.

```
\documentclass[ebook,oneside,openany,17pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}   %% for demo
\setsecnumformat{}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother

\providecommand\chapfont{}
\makechapterstyle{mychap}{
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\afterchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\chapfont{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \chapfont ##1
  }
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{-\baselineskip}
}
\chapterstyle{mychap}
\setsecheadstyle{\raggedright\large\sffamily\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{section}}
\tableofcontents*

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not working for me :( The TOC is still empty! I will post a image if you need it. Maybe is a problem with my latex configuration?

Comment: @xndrme Did you compile my code as such? Did it not compile?

Comment: Also when I click on the **Contents** link in the TOC it gets me to **Heading on level 2(subsection)**

Comment: Wait! Maybe I have a problem with my editor!? When I rerun the compilation it worked just fine!

Comment: @xndrme For table of contents, you have to compile atleast 2 times. Not a problem with editor.

Comment: I think your solution is fine. But when I integrate it to my document I'm having problems, will try a little more, if no solutions I will ask you ;)

Comment: Still note working for me, if you can please look at http://pastebin.com/QXUEbMbx to see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @xndrme It works for me. I have changed `\chapter*` to `\chapter` and so on, no need of `*` since you have `\setsecnumformat{}`  [see this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3wHgO.png)

Comment: It works now! the problem were the *! Thanks again an sorry if I stole your time :D

Comment: @xndrme You are welcome. No you didn't steal my time `;-)`. It is pleasure to be of some help always.